# Performance counters while load testing

Tags: asp.net, iis, com, memory-leaks, performancecounter

below some of the counter values while doing load testing using 250 users:

```
>     Gen2 heap size : 1124196
> #bytes in all heaps : 2172104
> #GC Handles: 926
> # of pinned objects: 11 Large Object Heap size: 87128
> # total commited bytes: 3350528 
> # total reserved bytes: 33546240
```

they were increasing, increasing till they reach that limit.

after the test finished, the memory shown in task manager for w3wp.exe is not releasing until an IIS Reset is applied.

also the application is not accessible till an IIS Reset is applied (getting com+ activation failed)

Anyone, had benn in that situation before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a tool like [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler&gclid=COzbo-WB8asCFRFR7AodKQMsIw).  Aside from that, make sure you are closing MemoryStreams, anything IO related, SqlConnections...etc.  Try to us [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements on anything that implements `IDisposable`.  Check for static references to objects tied to your `Page` instances.